How to use my nestjs auth apps in multiple applications
I have developed a nest authentication application. Now I want to use this code in multiple nestjs application. The auth app has it's own controllers.
I have tried to converting auth system to a library, but there it showing circular dependency on consuming app for @Injectrepository() from typeorm  used in auth app.
I want install it as a package, and then register it at the cosuming app and boooom, the controllers of auth app is available in the consuming app.
If not possibe as an packge then what is the best way to d this ?
